# using a string variable to ping and save a file in C++

Tags: c++, system, stdstring

```
system( "ping www.google.com  >  pingresult.txt")
```

From this code can the string `"ping www.google.com"`  be taken from an `std::string` variable? For example:

```
string ipAddress;

cout << "Enter the ip address: ";
cin >> ipAddress;

string ip = "ping" + ipAddress;
**system ("ip > pingresult.txt");** //error here
sytem("exit");
```

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

`ip` is not a shell command. I'm guessing you thought the string `"ip"` in the `system` call would be implicitly replaced with the string `ip` in your program; it doesn't work that way.

You can put the entire command string in `ip` then use the `.c_str()` method to convert the string to the `const char *` array that `system` expects:

```
ip += " > pingresult.txt";
system(ip.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first build the full command into an `std::string`, and then pass it as a `const char *` to the `system` function:

```
string ipAddress;

cout << "Enter the ip address: ";
cin >> ipAddress;

string cmd = "ping " + ipAddress + " > pingresult.txt";
system (cmd.c_str()); // pass a const char *
//system("exit"); this is a no-op spawning a new shell to only execute exit...
```

Comment: Well now i got it right Thank you very much!